# Can users connect to Moodle Chat with an IRC client?

Tags: irc, instant-messaging, moodle

[Moodle](http://moodle.org/) is an interesting Learning Management System. One of the tools it offers is a chat session. I don't know how it works under the hood, but the provided front-end is a weak javascript tool. Is there an IRC server hiding in there somewhere I can direct advanced users to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortuantly not, you'd need to run an IRCd for that which isn't included within Moodle.
Moddle just use a PHP/JS combination to emulate a chat room.

Comment: IRCd is an apt-get install away. Has anyone tried replacing the normal chat function with a full on IRC server?